# Data Packet Size

Tags: networking, network-protocols

I have a data of 25 bytes and would like to send it over a network. I would like to know how to calculate the minimum packet size if TCP is used over ipv4. All the net are exlaining it spearately only. I dont need to inculde the other protocaol or layer headers.

Thus i would like to what would be the size.

According to my research it is 20 TCP header + 20 ipv4 header + 25 bytes = 65 bytes is it correct ?

Comment: Don't forget to include any neccessary padding

Comment: @JanDvorak why need padding and on which layer

Comment: Why? -- each protocol can have its own padding. Which layer? -- you need to check all of them. Ethernet defines a minimum datagram size, TCP requires the header to be padded to a multiple of four bytes and might require the same for data.

Comment: There is no data padding in TCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither TCP nor IP uses padding, so

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure
  TCP headers are 20 bytes (+ options) in length. TCP doesn't add any padding. *If the data is 25 bytes, the TCP segment is 45 bytes or larger*.
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure
  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#page-34
  IPv4 headers are 20 bytes (+ options) in length. IPv4 doesn't add any padding. *If the TCP frame is 45 bytes, the IPv4 packet is 65 bytes or larger*.

Your results are correct.

Also,

- http://www.infocellar.com/networks/ethernet/frame.htm
  Ethernet headers are 14 bytes (assuming Ethernet2, not including the eight-byte preamble), and an ethernet frame ends with 4 bytes of CRC. Ethernet does not add any padding except to ensure a minimum of 64 bytes total. *If the IPv4 packet is 65 bytes, the Ethernet frame is 83 bytes*.